# Human population growth - where can I find the data?

Tags: human-biology, population-biology, database, demography

Out of curiosity, I'd like play around with data of human global demography.

Where can I find data that describe the "per region (per continent for example) population size" versus time since the "[Out-of-Africa Event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recent_African_origin_of_modern_humans#Movement_out_of_Africa)" or earlier?

Here is for example the kind of graph I'd like to reproduce but if possible in a region per region basis.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that data is available.. For recent data you can look at census of different regions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> National censuses are collected, published and disseminated primarily by each country's census or national statistical office (NSO) or its equivalent. Census data are published in each country's vernacular, and as appropriate, many offer English as well as other language versions.
>
> Statistical offices of international agencies (e.g. United Nations, statistical organizations for member states like the ASEAN, Eurostat, and OECD), also publish statistical data including population figures. The most consistent data in terms of format and frequency, whether online or in print are usually generated from them.

The US Library of congress provides some interesting links here:
http://www.loc.gov/rr/business/census/intlcensus.html

Also Cornell provides a few resources also:
https://www.ciser.cornell.edu/ASPs/datasource.asp

If you still need some information, your best bet is to then contact social scientists and ask for their opinion.