# World population pyramid since 1800

Tags: human-biology, population-dynamics, demography

I am interested in understanding how the global population pyramid has changed in the last couple of centuries.

I have two questions:

1) Has this been calculated? Are there estimates of population pyramids from the 19<sup>th</sup> century? Or from the beginning of 20<sup>th</sup> century? The earliest I have seen is 1950 ([below](https://ourworldindata.org/world-population-growth/#how-will-the-global-demography-will-change)).

2) If it hasn't been done, how can I construct it? It should be possible to model the population dynamics using birth and death rates (I would be surprised if this hasn't been done, as it has many applications outside of demography - e.g. economics).

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about Biology in the terms of SE Biology.

Comment: @David: I have edited the question to emphasise the population dynamics aspect. Similar questions have received answers, e.g. here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/what-is-the-percentage-of-people-living-in-england-in-1500-ad-whose-lineage-is-s?rq=1

Comment: Also this one here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/32981/human-population-growth-where-can-i-find-the-data?rq=1

Comment: Just because people answer questions that are not about biology sets no precedent. The site is adminstered by its users and not everything that should be is caught. I just call them as I see them. It will take another four like-minded reviewers to put your question on hold. They may not materialize.

Comment: Makes sense. Let's see how the others see it. And I would be of course happy to migrate the question elsewhere if anyone has ideas of a better fit.

Comment: Global seems like quite a far fetch to find out for one of us. It's therefore a research question, you would find out by searching for as old pyramids as you can find for various population types in the past and present and making an estimate of totally un-industrial types versus transition and modern types.

Comment: I am voting to close because it is a question of geography, not Biology.

Comment: @EOO The first post you link is clearly about population biology. The post you linked (which I asked), I agree, is arguably more about geography than biology.